# Why deadlocks occurs on two queries that access same table, but different data?

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

I have a multiple deadlocks when running multiple backups in parallel. I tried to read the graph but I have not so much experience with this part. What I found in the deadlock graph was that deadlock is key lock on index from the msdb and two different processes blocking each others but try to update different rows. Can someone explain me what could be the main reason for this type of deadlocks?

Here is deadlock graph :

```
<deadlock>
 <victim-list>
  <victimProcess id="process20e54e928" />
 </victim-list>
 <process-list>
  <process id="process20e54e928" taskpriority="-5" logused="308" waitresource="KEY: 4:72057594045595648 (50ff6b443fb9)" waittime="3554" ownerId="988275368" transactionname="UpdateMediaTables" lasttranstarted="2021-08-03T14:45:05.667" XDES="0x145a5216a8" lockMode="U" schedulerid="9" kpid="9784" status="suspended" spid="513" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="5" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2021-08-03T14:45:05.657" lastbatchcompleted="2021-08-03T14:45:05.653" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.653" clientapp="LiteSpeed {8f00e888-8df6-4145-9892-2f3af5bb8ff6}" hostname="Test-S01" hostpid="9036" loginname="Test\log_sqldev" isolationlevel="read uncommitted (1)" xactid="988275368" currentdb="1" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056" databaseName="master">
   <executionStack>
    <frame procname="adhoc" line="25" stmtstart="1310" stmtend="1612" sqlhandle="0x0200000039534e17d9721b50687cf558e78b288ea723ea020000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
UPDATE bs
    SET position = @BackupFileNumber, last_family_number = @MediaFamilyCount
    FROM msdb..backupset AS bs
    WHERE media_set_id = @MediaSetId    </frame>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

BEGIN TRAN UpdateMediaTables

DECLARE @SqlVersion int
DECLARE @LogDevName nvarchar(512)
DECLARE @MediaSetId int
DECLARE @FamilySequenceNumber tinyint
DECLARE @MaxFamilySequence tinyint
DECLARE @Mirror tinyint
DECLARE @BackupFileName nvarchar(1024)
DECLARE @BackupFileNumber int
DECLARE @MediaFamilyCount int
DECLARE @MirrorCount int
DECLARE @CompressedSize numeric(20, 0)
DECLARE @sql as nvarchar(4000)

SET @SqlVersion = @@microsoftversion / 0x1000000
SET @MediaSetId = 200455
SET @BackupFileNumber = 1
SET @MediaFamilyCount = 1
SET @MirrorCount = 1
SET @CompressedSize = 106496

UPDATE bs
    SET position = @BackupFileNumber, last_family_number = @MediaFamilyCount
    FROM msdb..backupset AS bs
    WHERE media_set_id = @MediaSetId

IF @SqlVersion &gt; 9  -- 2008+
BEGIN
    SET @sql = N'UPDATE bs SET compressed_backup_size = @CompressedSize FROM msdb..backupset AS bs
                 WHERE media_set_id = @MediaSetId'
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@Comp   </inputbuf>
  </process>
  <process id="processdfb7d5498" taskpriority="-5" logused="308" waitresource="KEY: 4:72057594045595648 (d9f96ec1035f)" waittime="3461" ownerId="988275200" transactionname="UpdateMediaTables" lasttranstarted="2021-08-03T14:45:05.600" XDES="0x11f8976d28" lockMode="U" schedulerid="3" kpid="8204" status="suspended" spid="495" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="5" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2021-08-03T14:45:05.583" lastbatchcompleted="2021-08-03T14:45:05.580" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.580" clientapp="LiteSpeed {b0d79b91-0265-4576-bce0-b5999783e72d}" hostname="Test-S01" hostpid="18688" loginname="Test\log_sqldev" isolationlevel="read uncommitted (1)" xactid="988275200" currentdb="1" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056" databaseName="master">
   <executionStack>
    <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="98" sqlhandle="0x0200000078af862e9eeb9ea061289180cc6cd1b56462cbb60000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
UPDATE bs SET compressed_backup_size = @CompressedSize FROM msdb..backupset AS bs
                 WHERE media_set_id = @MediaSetId    </frame>
    <frame procname="mssqlsystemresource.sys.sp_executesql" line="1" stmtstart="-1" sqlhandle="0x0400ff7f427f99d9010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
sp_executesql    </frame>
    <frame procname="adhoc" line="34" stmtstart="1982" stmtend="2258" sqlhandle="0x02000000b690a923e230bc3ce0b7ef99c90116c312eba0fc0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@CompressedSize numeric(20, 0), @MediaSetId int', @CompressedSize = @CompressedSize, @MediaSetId = @MediaSetId    </frame>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

BEGIN TRAN UpdateMediaTables

DECLARE @SqlVersion int
DECLARE @LogDevName nvarchar(512)
DECLARE @MediaSetId int
DECLARE @FamilySequenceNumber tinyint
DECLARE @MaxFamilySequence tinyint
DECLARE @Mirror tinyint
DECLARE @BackupFileName nvarchar(1024)
DECLARE @BackupFileNumber int
DECLARE @MediaFamilyCount int
DECLARE @MirrorCount int
DECLARE @CompressedSize numeric(20, 0)
DECLARE @sql as nvarchar(4000)

SET @SqlVersion = @@microsoftversion / 0x1000000
SET @MediaSetId = 200456
SET @BackupFileNumber = 1
SET @MediaFamilyCount = 1
SET @MirrorCount = 1
SET @CompressedSize = 947200

UPDATE bs
    SET position = @BackupFileNumber, last_family_number = @MediaFamilyCount
    FROM msdb..backupset AS bs
    WHERE media_set_id = @MediaSetId

IF @SqlVersion &gt; 9  -- 2008+
BEGIN
    SET @sql = N'UPDATE bs SET compressed_backup_size = @CompressedSize FROM msdb..backupset AS bs
                 WHERE media_set_id = @MediaSetId'
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@Comp   </inputbuf>
  </process>
 </process-list>
 <resource-list>
  <keylock hobtid="72057594045595648" dbid="4" objectname="msdb.dbo.backupset" indexname="PK__backupse__21F79AAB792B85D3" id="lock13c4d30b80" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594045595648" databaseName="msdb">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="processdfb7d5498" mode="X" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="process20e54e928" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
   </waiter-list>
  </keylock>
  <keylock hobtid="72057594045595648" dbid="4" objectname="msdb.dbo.backupset" indexname="PK__backupse__21F79AAB792B85D3" id="lock13f41a0180" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594045595648" databaseName="msdb">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="process20e54e928" mode="X" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="processdfb7d5498" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
   </waiter-list>
  </keylock>
 </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

Comment: Have you tried in `READ COMMITTED` isolation?

Comment: Since you appear to be using LiteSpeed, this might be a support question for Quest.